# Lambda expressions with multithreading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I am trying to understand why this program doesn't work

Expected output: numbers 0-19 in random order
What I get when I run: some numbers repeat, sometimes 20 is printed.

Please help. I tried with lock(obj) in DoSomething() but it didn't help.

### Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public delegate void callbackDelegate(int x);
    class Program
    {
        void processCallback(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IN callback: The value I got is " + x);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.processinThreads();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void DoSomething(int x, callbackDelegate callback)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("I just woke up now " + x);
            callback(x);
        }

        public void processinThreads()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Thread t = 
new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>DoSomething(i, processCallback)));
                t.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Captured Variable In Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop)

Comment: right, I couldn't get this when I searched for this problem. Well I don't know this 'closure over lambda problem' :)

Comment: Avoid manual thread creation. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397729/how-do-you-get-list-of-running-threads-in-c/9405662#9405662) is a detailed explanation with benchmarks why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void processinThreads()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int local = i;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>DoSomething(local, processCallback)));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Your problem is related to closure over lambda.

Comment: Check out this article: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). It will be fixed in C# 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

You should just use the TPL, its a lot easier and **recommended over manual thread management**:

```
Parallel.For(0, 20, x => {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("IN callback: The value I got is " + x);
});
```

This will also block until the loop finishes, if you don't want that you can use the TPL `Task`, but I would definitely recommend avoiding threads.

Comment: Moreover, this is likely to be more efficient: Spawning another thread is pretty expensive. The TPL uses an (automagically computed) optimum number of threads and re-uses them.

Comment: @user676571 I am planning to use TPL with Async pattern applied.

Answer (score 1):

As Jakub already told you, you need to copy `i` into another local variable `local`. In your code, the Delegates have direct access to `i` itself, not a copy of `i`, so they print out the very current value of `i`, which may be greater than when you started the thread. This is called closure.