# Looping through a list of Actions

Tags: c#, action, enumeration

I can't understand how to loop through an `Action` list. When I try it, I end up with the values being the same as the previous iteration.

Here's the code (simplified example):

```
string[] strings = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };

var actions = new List<Action>();
foreach (string str in strings)
    actions.Add(new Action(() => { Trace.WriteLine(str); }));

foreach (var action in actions)
    action();
```

Output:

```
ghi
ghi
ghi
```

Why is it always selecting the final element in `strings` when it performs the action?
And how can I achieve the desired output which would be:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your action is a closure, therefore it accesses `str` itself, not a copy of `str`:

```
foreach (string str in strings)
{
    var copy = str; // this will do the job
    actions.Add(new Action(() => { Trace.WriteLine(copy); }));
}
```

Comment: Gah, you win. I knew how to fix it, but I couldn't remember the reason why. Closure! I need closure! +1 :)

Comment: @Joshua it wasn't too long ago when I learnt in a little deeper :) ... this may be good for further reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412672/lambda-expressions-with-multithreading-in-c-sharp

Comment: Interesting, I never realised. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is conditionize by [Closures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/17/what-are-closures.aspx).

The variable that is present in your lambda is a **reference** and **not** value copy. That means that points to the latest value assumed by `str`, which is "ghi" in your case. That's why for every call it just goes to the *same* memory location and recovers, naturally, same value.

If you write the code, like in answers provided, you force a `C#` compiler to regenerate a **new** value each time, so a **new** address will be passed to the labmda, so every lambda will have it's **own** variable.

By the way, if I'm not mistake, `C#` team promise to fix this *non natural* behaviour in `C# 5.0`. So it's better to check their blog on this subject for future updates.

Comment: +1 good explanation. It may be worth mentioning that Java does it the other way. If you deal with `Runnable` (typically) to start a thread, the variables are *copied* in to the new context. This is also why Java forces you to make them `final`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty complicated situation. The short answer is to create a copy of the local variable before assigning it to the closure:

```
string copy = str;
actions.Add(new Action(() => { Trace.WriteLine(copy); }));
```

[Check out this article on closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for more information.