# C# Closure works?

Tags: c#, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)
>   [Looping through a list of Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569334/looping-through-a-list-of-actions)

today I encounter a problem about the C# foreach function, it didn't give me the proper result as I expected. here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<Func<int>> actions = new List<Func<int>>();
        foreach (int x in data)
        {
            actions.Add(delegate() { return x; });
        }
        foreach (var foo in actions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo());   
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

when I Run it in console application and it has five 5 printed on the screen. Why? I just cann't understand. Have asked some people and they just said that there is closure in this code, But I am not very clear about this, I remember that in javascript , I often encounter the closure, but in above code, why there is closure? thx.

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569334/looping-through-a-list-of-actions/

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: This question is asked almost every day. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach/8899347#8899347 for a good discussion of the issue.

Answer (score 6):

In C#4 all iterations of a `foreach` loop share the same variable, and thus the same closure.

The specification says:

> ```
> foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> is then expanded to:
>
> ```
> {  
>   E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator(); 
>   try
>   { 
>     V v; 
>     while (e.MoveNext())
>     { 
>       v = (V)(T)e.Current; 
>
>       embedded-statement 
>     } 
>   } 
>   finally
>   {  
>     … // Dispose e 
>   } 
> }
> ```

You can see that `v` is declared in a block outside the `while`-loop, which causes this sharing behavior.

This will probably be changed in C#5.

> We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: why this earlier spec says v is declared inside the while loop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa664754.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The key is that when you are creating the delegates within your `foreach` loop you are creating a closure over the loop *variable* `x`, **not its current value**.

Only when you execute the delegates in `actions` will the value be determined, which is the **value of** `x` **at that time**. Since you have completed the `foreach` loop by then the value will be the last item in your `data` array which is 5.

Comment: +1: very clear and concise explanation.

Comment: It's important to note, that the last sentence is only true for C#4 and earlier.

Comment: ..as you pointed out already, so I didn't feel like repeating it ;-)